# Is there a performance cost to create an infinite event loop using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

If I need an event loop in javascript to run forever (perhaps querying a REST api inside the loop), is there any performance penalty if it is implemented as follows

```
function eventLoop() {
// Call to REST api
requestAnimationFrame(eventLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(eventLoop);
```

or as shown here

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ltseg

Comment: It would be far better to trigger the next query after the previous one completes. The way you described would have multiple requests in flight at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`requestAnimationFrame` is meant for, as the name implies, rendering animations. It has a high rate of iteration up to around 60 fps. That sounds like overkill if you're polling an API (which presumably will take a chunk of time for a response to be returned).

Why not simply use `setTimeout`? You could poll the API, and then when the request is returned, optionally poll again.

```
var timer;

function pollAPI() {
    $.ajax({
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == 'something') {
            // do something
        } else {
            // poll again
            timer = setTimeout(pollAPI, 50);
        }
      }
    });
}

pollAPI();
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is much better than `setTimeout` in that sens that it provides the best number of iterations regarding to CPU capacities. It also stops when the window looses its focus.

Comment: Right, but O.P. specified that they're trying to query a REST API in the loop. For something like that, it's better to control the number of requests, rather than firing multiple requests at 60 fps.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly fine, but if you're doing something async across the internet like ajax calls you should wait an appropriate amount of time before re-firing or you'll end up sending 60 requests a second to yourself.